# side by side COM component versions on Windows Server 2000

Tags: windows-server-2000, dll, com

Is it possible to have different versions of a COM component installed and callable on a Windows 2000 server, much like [Registration-Free COM components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) in Windows Server 2003 onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it works like it does in 203 but yes you can have multiple com versions installed and callable see [Implementing Side-by-Side Component Sharing in Applications (Expanded)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811700.aspx)